# IIS site from Mac OS shared folder

Tags: asp.net, macos, iis

I'm trying to run an ASP website on an IIS in a Windows PC (not virtual machine) which sources are in a Mac Shared Folder, this is what I have tried:

1. On mac I shared the sources with user "user123"
2. On the Windows PC I've created the user "user123" in Computer Management
3. Created an IIS site with Pyshical path: \\MAC_IP_ADDRESS\WebSite, and set Connect As.. Specific User to "user123"
4. Also I set Anonymous authentication and Application Pool Authentication to "user123"

Everything loads fine but web service calls on asmx files gives the
[following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr77L.png)

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

I would appreciate your help! Thanks!

**NOTE:** I have a vmware Windows virtual machine hosted in the Mac running the website and it's working just fine.

Comment: Unless the remote file share is Windows based, or strictly certified by Microsoft, it won't work this way. I don't think Apple ever asks Microsoft to certify this.

Comment: Ok, so maybe there's no way to make it work with a physical windows device. I say this because I have a windows vmware virtual machine working fine with this same configuration (virtual machine is hosted in the Mac where the source code is)

Answer (score 0):

I think there could probably have some difference between VMware and external IIS server.

I tried to monitor the process via process monitor and it seems to be an authentication operation instead of normal I/O operation. IIS should return that error because 0xC000005E **There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.**

If I want to access share folder between two windows server machines:

In non-domain environment, you could:

1.Create a user with same password and username on both server.

2.Grant the user **read/write** permission to access the folder. Because IIS will try to create web.config in that folder.

3.Replace IIS anonymous user and application pool to that new user account.

Since I'm not sure whether it is available to let MAC authenticate Windows credential, it would probably a bit hard to achieve this.

Of course, you could try to use process monitor to monitor the operation. Maybe it will help us find a way to achieve this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Hello Jokies, thanks for your time! and sorry for the late response. I've tried that already :/ but same result, I will monitor the process so I can give you detailed information about it.